# how to pivot/unpivot (cast/melt) data frame?

Tags: r, pivot-table, reshape, reshape2

How can I 'unpivot' a table? What is the proper technical term for this?

UPDATE: The term is called **melt**

I have a data frame for countries and data for each year

```
Country     2001    2002    2003
Nigeria     1       2       3
UK          2       NA       1
```

And I want to have something like

```
Country    Year    Value
Nigeria    2001    1
Nigeria    2002    2
Nigeria    2003    3
UK         2001    2
UK         2002    NA
UK         2003    1
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I still can't believe I beat Andrie with an answer. :)

```
> library(reshape)
> my.df <- read.table(text = "Country     2001    2002    2003
   + Nigeria     1       2       3
   + UK          2       NA       1", header = TRUE)
> my.result <- melt(my.df, id = c("Country"))
> my.result[order(my.result$Country),]
     Country variable value
   1 Nigeria    X2001     1
   3 Nigeria    X2002     2
   5 Nigeria    X2003     3
   2      UK    X2001     2
   4      UK    X2002    NA
   6      UK    X2003     1
```

Comment: you beat me too.  Also try: `check.names=FALSE` when reading to get years without X prepended, or `sub("^X","",variable)` to strip them off later; and `as.numeric(variable)` to convert back to a numeric value

Comment: Thanks! I guess then that the technical term is to 'melt' the table. Right?

Comment: Yes -- at least that's probably the most common term used in R circles, thanks to the amazing `reshape` package (which introduced the terminology of "melting" and "casting", as far as I know)

Comment: +1 Who's using R 2.14 then?  Look at that `text=` argument to `read.table`!

Answer (score 5):

The base R `reshape` approach for this problem is pretty ugly, particularly since the names aren't in a form that `reshape` likes. It would be something like the following, where the first `setNames` line modifies the column names into something that `reshape` can make use of.

```
reshape(
  setNames(mydf, c("Country", paste0("val.", c(2001, 2002, 2003)))), 
  direction = "long", idvar = "Country", varying = 2:ncol(mydf), 
  sep = ".", new.row.names = seq_len(prod(dim(mydf[-1]))))
```

---

A better alternative in base R is to use `stack`, like this:

```
cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1]))
#   Country values  ind
# 1 Nigeria      1 2001
# 2      UK      2 2001
# 3 Nigeria      2 2002
# 4      UK     NA 2002
# 5 Nigeria      3 2003
# 6      UK      1 2003
```

---

There are also new tools for reshaping data now available, like the "tidyr" package, which gives us `gather`. Of course, the `tidyr:::gather_.data.frame` method just calls `reshape2::melt`, so this part of my answer doesn't necessarily add much except introduce the newer syntax that you might be encountering in the Hadleyverse.

```
library(tidyr)
gather(mydf, year, value, `2001`:`2003`) ## Note the backticks
#   Country year value
# 1 Nigeria 2001     1
# 2      UK 2001     2
# 3 Nigeria 2002     2
# 4      UK 2002    NA
# 5 Nigeria 2003     3
# 6      UK 2003     1
```

---

All three options here would need reordering of rows if you want the row order you showed in your question.

---

A fourth option would be to use `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package. Like base R's `reshape`, you'll need to modify the column names to something that includes a "variable" and "time" indicator.

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(
  setNames(mydf, c("Country", paste0("V.", 2001:2003))),
  var.stubs = "V", sep = ".")
#    Country .time_1  V
# 1: Nigeria    2001  1
# 2: Nigeria    2002  2
# 3: Nigeria    2003  3
# 4:      UK    2001  2
# 5:      UK    2002 NA
# 6:      UK    2003  1
```

---

#### Sample data

```
 mydf <- structure(list(Country = c("Nigeria", "UK"), `2001` = 1:2, `2002` = c(2L, 
     NA), `2003` = c(3L, 1L)), .Names = c("Country", "2001", "2002",               
     "2003"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Backticks for the column subset...?  Why.  I was just getting good at dplyr too. Haha

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `melt` command from the `reshape` package. See here: http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html

Probably something like `melt(myframe, id=c('Country'))`