# Convert Dataframe to key value pair list in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to pivot/unpivot (cast/melt) data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980030/how-to-pivot-unpivot-cast-melt-data-frame)

I have this data frame

```
idx A  B  C  D
1   12 23 33 4
2   33 22 23 6
```

which I would like to convert to the following format (which `ggplot2` seems to prefer)

```
idx col value
1   A   12
1   B   23
1   C   33
1   D   4
2   A   33
2   B   22
2   C   23
2   D   6
```

Is there any way to do it with standard R code (or a `ggplot2` function that I am missing)?

Comment: You are looking for `reshape2::melt`.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980030/how-to-pivot-unpivot-cast-melt-data-frame) as one of many duplicates.

Comment: Adapted from an answer to that question, here is the exact code that you need: `melt(x, id='idx', variable_name='col')`

Comment: Thanks, as an R newbie I am not exactly familiar with the terminology, hence the duplicate...

Comment: @GeorgiosGousios: R-newb or not, you have a responsibility to search before posting. True that terminology can vary, but if you post your search strategies, people will probably be less quick to close and more inclined to offer explanations.