# Sum up with "keyword" in header with R

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

My dataset has hundreds column of data in data.frame, every column's header name is a city's name + its state's abbreviation. I am not sure what is the "separated sign" between the city's name and state's name, I want to delete all the city's name to get a new data.frame.
Like:
[image]

I tried this way, but it doesn't work, it seems like those words are not separated by ".."

```
Header = c(colnames(CityValue))
split_fun = function(str){
    strsplit(str,"..")[[1]][1]
}
sapply(Header, split_fun)
```

I got :

[image]

Comment: Melt your data frame with reshape2, split *variable* into 2 columns like city & state, and sum as usually.

Comment: This is a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/q/7980030/673826 and let's say http://stackoverflow.com/q/7069076/673826

Comment: How can I split variable into 2 clumns like city&state?

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. Besides mentioned everywhere combination of strsplit, do.call, and rbind, there is off-the-shelf [colsplit from reshape2](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/reshape2/docs/colsplit).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried use the strsplit like this:                                         Header = c(colnames(CityValue))split_fun = function(str){
  strsplit(str,",")[[1]][1]
}
sapply(Header, split_fun)            CityValue is the name of data.frame I want split, but I found it seems like , those colnames are not separate by ".." like we can directly see, How can I know what "divided benchmark" should I use to spilt?