# Melt data frame row by row

Tags: r, reshape, melt

How can I melt a data frame row by row?
I found a really [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980030/how-to-pivot-unpivot-cast-melt-data-frame) on the forum but I still can't solve my problem without a different id variable.

This is my data set:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
51 20 29 12 20
51 22 51 NA NA
51 14 NA NA NA
51 75 NA NA NA
```

And I want to melt it into:

```
V1 variable value    
51 V2 20
51 V3 29
51 V4 12
51 V5 20
51 V2 22
51 V3 51
51 V2 14
51 V2 75
```

Currently my approach is melting it row by row with a for loop and then rbind them together.

```
library(reshape)

df <- read.table(text = "V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 51 20 29 12 20 51 22 51 NA NA 51 
+14 NA NA NA 51 75 NA NA NA", header = TRUE)

dfall<-NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(df))
{
  dfmelt<-melt(df,id="V1",na.rm=TRUE)
  dfall<-rbind(dfall,dfmelt)
}
```

Just wondering if there is any way to do this faster? Thanks!

Comment: Check out tidyr::gather but doesn't melt achieve what you want?

Comment: @chinsoon12 nope, melt will do it column by column i.e., the "value" column will be 20,22,14,75,29,51,12,20 instead of 20,29,12,20,22,51,14,75

Comment: I posted a solution.  You can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We replicate the first column "V1" and the `names` of the dataset except the first column name to create the first and second column of the expected output, while the 'value' column is created by transposing the dataset without the first column.

```
na.omit(data.frame(V1=df1[1][col(df1[-1])],
             variable = names(df1)[-1][row(df1[-1])],
              value = c(t(df1[-1]))))
#   V1 variable value
#1  51       V2    20
#2  51       V3    29
#3  51       V4    12
#4  51       V5    20
#5  51       V2    22
#6  51       V3    51
#9  51       V2    14
#13 51       V2    75
```

NOTE: No additional packages used.

---

Or we can use `gather` (from `tidyr`) to convert the 'wide' to 'long' format after we create a row id column (`add_rownames` from `dplyr`) and then `arrange` the rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
add_rownames(df1) %>% 
        gather(variable, value, V2:V5, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
        arrange(rowname, V1) %>% 
        select(-rowname)
#      V1 variable value
#    (int)    (chr) (int)
#1    51       V2    20
#2    51       V3    29
#3    51       V4    12
#4    51       V5    20
#5    51       V2    22
#6    51       V3    51
#7    51       V2    14
#8    51       V2    75
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1, keep.rownames=TRUE),
      id.var= c("rn", "V1"), na.rm=TRUE)[
      order(rn, V1)][, rn:= NULL][]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Never thought of doing it this way, was stuck in "how to melt a data frame"

Answer (score 2):

You can make a column with a unique ID for each row, so you can sort on it after melting. Using `dplyr`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(id = seq_len(n())) %>% 
    melt(id.var = c('V1','id'), na.rm = T) %>% 
    arrange(V1, id, variable) %>% 
    select(-id)
#   V1 variable value
# 1 51       V2    20
# 2 51       V3    29
# 3 51       V4    12
# 4 51       V5    20
# 5 51       V2    22
# 6 51       V3    51
# 7 51       V2    14
# 8 51       V2    75
```

...or base R:

```
library(reshape2)
df$id <- seq_along(df$V1)
df2 <- melt(df, id.var = c('V1', 'id'), na.rm = TRUE)
df2[order(df2$V1, df2$id, df2$variable),-2]
```