# How to edit excel table by converting row values to column values

Tags: r, database, excel, excel-2010, excel-2016

[image]

I have above  table containing latitude and longitude values, But latitudes are in column & longitudes are in row, I want both in column wise and with their corresponding values

Comment: The action you're looking for is called unpivot. You can find plenty of tips already on the internet.

Comment: Useful pointers for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980030/how-to-pivot-unpivot-cast-melt-data-frame, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the desired output?
I guess you can use reshape package.

```
library(reshape)
df <- read.table("your_file")
result <- melt(df, id = c("name"))
```